# Drywall ceiling in basement of multi family dwelling required by IBC

Tags: drywall, basement, ceiling

In a multi family dwelling is a drywall ceiling required by IBC in basement area  below living area? 5/8 X?  Property has 9 dwelling units in Baltimore City which uses IBC latest updates 2017. Area of concern in basement was previously a 10th unit but being converted to basement/utility/storage and part of old ceiling has been removed. The main part of basement is equipped with heat sensors connected to fire alarm system due to furnaces/water heaters. In that part of basement sheetrock is not required due to the heat sensors.

Another property has a 'basement' area dug out in the center of the building. The rear portion which is under the first and second floor apartments has a crawl space and a heat sensor but the front portion which is under a one story room of the first floor apartment has no sensor.  Is one required under IBC?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. We'll probably need more information before we can help you.

Comment: Can you give us what edition of the IBC your city/county/state is on, and what makes you believe the IBC applies instead of the IRC?  (Generally, the IRC is used for single and two family dwellings and townhomes, while the IBC applies to commercial and mixed-use buildings, as well as apartments)